# Can we use special characters for Windows passwords?

Tags: windows, passwords, bitlocker, special-characters

I was wondering if we can use special characters in Windows password. I tried to use '♥' in bitlocker, the password was set.

But when I tried to unlock the drive. I couldn't print this character by either <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3331</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. I had to use a notepad and then I copied my password from notepad to bitlocker's password box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have `¬` (logical negation) in my Windows password. I used this is various passwords for various tools/applications. The biggest problem with it was that some devices/OS's don't have support for that character (e.g. iPhone iOS). I would recommend using characters that can be consumed on any keyboard device.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt Not to nitpick on flem's answer, but wouldn't you want a definitive reference telling you that is OK to use these characters, before trusting your data to it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which software you are using. But it’s not adviced to use *so* special characters since they aren’t in the primary ASCII table. Note that on linux, I have a bépo keyboard layout, and I use special characters for my unix password (because it allows it to).